# Service Fabric Client REST API - Syntax for parameters in body

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to use the client rest api to upgrade an application.  I can get the application types, version etc using the api but I'm struggling when trying the "Start Application Upgrade".  The problem looks like it's with the encoding of the Application Upgrade Description, all the ways I've tried I can't get past

```
{
    "Error": {
        "Code": "FABRIC_E_INVALID_NAME_URI",
        "Message": "Invalid name URI."
    }
}
```

I could be way off but I'm using JSON format like below for the body:

```
{
"ApplicationUpgradeDescription":{
    "Name":"fabric:/twinpeaks",
    "TargetVersion":"1.0.1",
    …..other params as per spec
}
```

Any pointers?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Close but not quite..  The body just needs to be:

```
{
    "Name":"fabric:/twinpeaks",
     "TargetApplicationTypeVersion":"1.1.0",
     ….. etc
}
```

Once I made this change the upgrade was accepted, all good.